# Creating a FloatArray from an Array<Float> object in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a Array object to a FloatArray using a spread operator:

```
val x = arrayOf(0.2f, 0.3f)
val y = floatArrayOf(*x)
```

Unfortunetly I get Type mismatch: `inferred type is Array<Float> but FloatArray was expected`

Why is there an error and how to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write that but instead you can do:

```
val y = x.toFloatArray()
```

Answer (score 3):

[`toFloatArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-float-array.html) is the obvious choice, but if for some reason you wanted to create a new float array without calling that, you could do the same thing it does internally: call the `FloatArray` [constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-float-array/#constructors):

```
val x = arrayOf(0.2f, 0.3f)
val y = FloatArray(x.size) { x[it] }
```